# visual studio code debug code does not match gopath using golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

visual studio code using golang  debugger does not match the gopath path code ?

I construct up golang environment using visual studio code IDE **MAC OS**, then install the necessary tools:

```
go get -v -u github.com/peterh/liner github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
go get -u -v github.com/nsf/gocode
go get -u -v github.com/rogpeppe/godef
go get -u -v github.com/golang/lint/golint
go get -u -v github.com/lukehoban/go-find-references
go get -u -v github.com/lukehoban/go-outline
go get -u -v sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns
go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename
go get -u -v github.com/tpng/gopkgs
go get -u -v github.com/newhook/go-symbols
```

I ever set my go path `/Users/friends/gopath` , before long I changed my gopath `/Users/friends/Document/share/gopath`. I changed the gopath **~/.bash_profile** ,**visual studio code setting** about

`go.gopath": "/Users/friends/Documents/VirtualMachine/share/gopath`

when I debug my code, it tips that **can't find** the file in`/Users/friends/gopath/src/...../apiSGetChainsIds.go` , actually the file exist in `/Users/friends/Documents/VirtualMachine/share/gopath/src/..../apiSGetChainsIds.go` .It is obvious that the debugger find the previous `gopath` ,is it the golang tools bug? or something I wrong?

my usersetting is

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
     //"go.buildOnSave": "package",
     //"go.lintOnSave": "package",
     //"go.vetOnSave": "package",
     "go.buildFlags": [],
     "go.lintFlags": [],
     "go.vetFlags": [],
     "go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": false,
     "go.formatOnSave": false,
     "go.formatTool": "goreturns",
     "editor.fontSize": 14,
     "go.goroot": "/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec",
     "go.gopath": "/Users/friends/Documents/VirtualMachine/share/gopath"

    }
```

Comment: In `go.gopath` value, replace tilde prefix (`~`) with actual directory, since it's shell specific, perhaps not being replaced by the vscode. If you define the `GOPATH` in `.bash_profile`, use GOPATH instead of `go.gopath`.

Comment: sorry, actually I use the absolute path , it can not works. I have edit my question description ~ to /Users/friends

Comment: It is obvious, the error message is not *exactly* the same with `go.gopath` value. Verify *current GOPATH* in vscode through menu: `View->Command Palette...->Go: Current GOPATH`. Also check the value of `go.inferGopath` in vscode settings (the default value is `false`, please use the default value).

Comment: What do you mean by through menu: View->Command Palette...->Go: Current GOPATH ?      I type in `go env` , it shows `GOPATH="/Users/friends/Documents/VirtualMachine/share/gopath"`, and `go.inferGopath `  does not changed.

Comment: I mean, click menu `View` and then `Command Palette...` in your vscode IDE. I think your problem is related to [https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code#cannot-find-package--in-any-of-](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code#cannot-find-package--in-any-of-).

Comment: command palette shows `Current GOPATH: /Users/friends/Documents/VirtualMachine/share/gopath`, actually in my launch.json , it written `        "env": { "CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL": "WARNING", "GOPATH": "/Users/friends/Documents/VirtualMachine/share/gopath" },
`

Answer (score 1):

I had also the problem to get it to run today, and here is what was necessary:

1. get your self delve (https://github.com/derekparker/delve)

   either a) if you prefer to build and install it, clone the repo to

   ~/go/src/github.com/derekparker/delve

and then run:

```
go install github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
```

because of latest macOS security updates, you need also to code sign it:

```
codesign -s dlv-cert $(which dlv)
```

or b) try brew

2. add a launch configuration into launch.json, my working looked as follows:

"configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Launch Package",
                "type": "go",
                "request": "launch",
                "mode": "debug",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}/myAppPackagePath/",
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "args": ["option1","option2","..."],
                "showLog": true
            }
        ]

Comment: delve doesn't install in windows 32 architecture.